# How to Iterate through an Unordered List to get a console.log of the innerText of the LI element

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, innertext

I need to create an event-listener which fires when a user clicks one of the list items in the HTML.The action should call a function named listItemText which returns the innerText of the list item which was clicked--ie: if they click the first li it should log "Walk the dog"

I've tried everything I can think of to get the correct corresponding innerText of the li item that is being clicked on. At best, I've gotten either the whole list back in the console.log, or the last element of the list.

I've tried so many things at this point it would be impossible to recall. More or less the code below is a variant of what I've attempted

```
  <ul id="todo-app">
      <li class="item">Walk the dog</li>
      <li class="item">Pay bills</li>
      <li class="item">Make dinner</li>
      <li class="item">Code for one hour</li>
  </ul>
```

```
var targetUl = document.getElementById('todo-app').childNodes;

this.addEventListener('click', listItemText);

function listItemText(event) {
  var liClicked = event.target;

  for (i=0; i<targetUl.length; i++) {
    if (liClicked == 'LI') {
      console.log(targetUl[i].innerText)
    }
  } 
}
```

I expect to get the text content of the li tag but I keep getting undefined at this point. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want the `console.log` of the text of the `li` element you click, so I suppose you can try this code below:

```js
var targetUl = document.getElementById('todo-app').addEventListener("click",listItemText);

function listItemText(event) {
  var liClicked = event.target;
  if(liClicked && liClicked.nodeName == "LI"){
    console.log(liClicked.textContent)
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="todo-app">
      <li class="item">Walk the dog</li>
      <li class="item">Pay bills</li>
      <li class="item">Make dinner</li>
      <li class="item">Code for one hour</li>
</ul>
```

This is the principle of event delegation, where you don't need to attach event listeners on all of the elements but only to the parent node, if the event happened it will bubble up to the parent and using the `event.target` you can get the reference of the child element which was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I just now ended up figuring it out. Did it slightly differently, but ultimately the same idea. Was having a hard time understanding event.target and how it works. Here's my answer--which is almost the same as your answer, good sir:

```
var toDoList = document.getElementById("todo-app");
toDoList.addEventListener('click', listItemText);

function listItemText(e) {
  console.log(e.target.innerText);
  return e.target.innerText;
}
```